# Changing UIPickerView's font size from HTML5

Tags: html, uipickerview

How do I set a UiPickerView's (in iphone/itouch)font size from HTML5. The situation is i am writing a mobile web page which has a dropdown. The drop down text seems to spill out of the uipickerview which show up when the user selects the dropdown. Is there a way to control the spill? My solution was to decrease the font size of the uiPickerView control. I am not very sure if we can control a native control from html. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.